# Using Python 3 time.sleep in Raspberry Pi 3 hangs process

Tags: python-3.x, docker, raspberry-pi3

If I execute a Python 3 script inside my Raspberry Pi 3 and it uses `time.sleep(wait)`, it only works interactively. If I background the process using `&`, the script doesn't seem to work at all and I don't see any output in my CSV file the script writes to. It stays at file size `0` forever.

I've tried this by running a script directly (`read-sensor >/var/lib/envirophat/sensor.csv &`) and the same inside a Docker container (I'm using HypriotOS).

How can I read the sensor faster than once per minute (using `crontab`) but not continuously without any kind of `sleep`?

Comment: I doubt it's time.sleep that is the problem. You might have a buffering issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the output buffering was in fact the issue. It was working but never outputting anything so I couldn't tell. Using python3 -u seems to do the trick. I updated my Docker image to reflect this.